# r - Find all combinations excluding those from the same group

Tags: r, join

I have groups of points.  I want the combination of a point with every other point, excluding points that are in the same group as it.

Consider the example data:

```
Group  Longitude  Latitude
Group1 1.5        4.0
Group1 3.0        5.0
Group1 1.3        3.0
Group2 2.0        8.0
Group2 0.7        6.5
Group3 2.0        3.0
```

Then my desired output would be something like:

```
GroupA  LongitudeA  LatitudeA  GroupB  LongitudeB  LatitudeB
Group1  1.5         4.0        Group2  2.0         8.0
Group1  1.5         4.0        Group2  0.7         6.5
Group1  1.5         4.0        Group3  2.0         3.0
Group1  3.0         5.0        Group2  2.0         8.0 
Group1  3.0         5.0        Group2  0.7         6.5
Group1  3.0         5.0        Group3  2.0         3.0
```

etc.

Reproducible data:

```
structure(list(Group = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2", 
"Group 2", "Group 3"), Longitude = c(1.5, 3, 1.3, 2, 0.7, 2), 
Latitude = c(4, 5, 3, 8, 6.5, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Group = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve this with a cartesian SQL join that filters all rows where `Group = Group_B`. This is a straightforward operation with the `sqldf` package.

```
data_a <-
     structure(
          list(
               Group = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 2",
                         "Group 2", "Group 3"),
               Longitude = c(1.5, 3, 1.3, 2, 0.7, 2),
               Latitude = c(4, 5, 3, 8, 6.5, 3)
          ),
          class = "data.frame",
          row.names = c(NA,-6L),
          spec = structure(list(
               cols = list(
                    Group = structure(list(), class =
                                           c("collector_character",
                                             "collector")),
                    Longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                            "collector")),
                    Latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                           "collector"))
               ),
               default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                                     "collector")),
               skip = 1
          ), class = "col_spec")
     )
```

After reading the data, we copy it to a second data frame and rename the columns in the second data frame by appending `_B` to each column name.

```
data_b <- data_a 

colnames(data_b) <- paste(colnames(data_b),"_B",sep="")
```

Then we load `sqldf` and execute an SQL query that creates a cartesian product of `data_a` and `data_b`, matching every row in `data_a` with every row in `data_b`. The `where` clause eliminates every row in the result set where `Group` is equal to `Group_B`.

```
library(sqldf)

sqlStmt <- c('select * from data_a, data_b 
             where "Group" <> "Group_B"')
joined <- sqldf(sqlStmt)
```

...and the output:

```
> joined

     Group Longitude Latitude Group_B Longitude_B Latitude_B
1  Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 2         2.0        8.0
2  Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 2         0.7        6.5
3  Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
4  Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 2         2.0        8.0
5  Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 2         0.7        6.5
6  Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
7  Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 2         2.0        8.0
8  Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 2         0.7        6.5
9  Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
10 Group 2       2.0      8.0 Group 1         1.5        4.0
11 Group 2       2.0      8.0 Group 1         3.0        5.0
12 Group 2       2.0      8.0 Group 1         1.3        3.0
13 Group 2       2.0      8.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
14 Group 2       0.7      6.5 Group 1         1.5        4.0
15 Group 2       0.7      6.5 Group 1         3.0        5.0
16 Group 2       0.7      6.5 Group 1         1.3        3.0
17 Group 2       0.7      6.5 Group 3         2.0        3.0
18 Group 3       2.0      3.0 Group 1         1.5        4.0
19 Group 3       2.0      3.0 Group 1         3.0        5.0
20 Group 3       2.0      3.0 Group 1         1.3        3.0
21 Group 3       2.0      3.0 Group 2         2.0        8.0
22 Group 3       2.0      3.0 Group 2         0.7        6.5
```

If the output needs to eliminate rows where the groups are reversed (i.e. a point where a `Group` value of 2 is matched with a `Group_B` equal to 1), one can do this as follows:

```
sqlStmt <- c('select * from data_a, data_b 
             where "Group" < "Group_B"')
joined <- sqldf(sqlStmt)

joined
```

...and the output:

```
> joined
     Group Longitude Latitude Group_B Longitude_B Latitude_B
1  Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 2         2.0        8.0
2  Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 2         0.7        6.5
3  Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
4  Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 2         2.0        8.0
5  Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 2         0.7        6.5
6  Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
7  Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 2         2.0        8.0
8  Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 2         0.7        6.5
9  Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
10 Group 2       2.0      8.0 Group 3         2.0        3.0
11 Group 2       0.7      6.5 Group 3         2.0        3.0
```

Comment: But you need to remove duplicates e.g rows 1 and 10

Comment: @LocoGris - from the question it wasn't clear to me whether row 1 is equal to row 10, but if it is, I added code to eliminate all rows where Group 2 <= Group, which eliminates the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code like below

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  combn(split(1:nrow(df), df$Group),
    2,
    FUN = function(x) {
      u <- expand.grid(x)
      cbind(df[u[, 1], ], df[u[, 2], ])
    },
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
      Group Longitude Latitude   Group Longitude Latitude
1   Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 2       2.0      8.0
2   Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 2       2.0      8.0
3   Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 2       2.0      8.0
1.1 Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 2       0.7      6.5
2.1 Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 2       0.7      6.5
3.1 Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 2       0.7      6.5
11  Group 1       1.5      4.0 Group 3       2.0      3.0
21  Group 1       3.0      5.0 Group 3       2.0      3.0
31  Group 1       1.3      3.0 Group 3       2.0      3.0
4   Group 2       2.0      8.0 Group 3       2.0      3.0
5   Group 2       0.7      6.5 Group 3       2.0      3.0
```